# How can I save the video recording from the camera module to an USB drive?

Tags: camera, raspicam, raspivid

I know that I record by issuing the command `raspivid -o filename.h264 -t 100000` (film for 100 seconds) but how do I specify the directory at witch I want to store the file?

Usb is at `dev/sdb1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a directory for and mount the filesystem on the USB drive.

```
mkdir /mnt/usb
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
```

Then you can specify the directory of where the USB drive is now mounted in the same command you issued before, like this:

```
raspivid -o /mnt/usb/filename.h264 -t 100000
```

Comment: Does the camera store the video on the MicroSd card first and then transferes to the USB drive or does it store it there directly?

Comment: Directly to usb. By mounting the usb drive partition (named: `/dev/sdb1`) onto the directory `/mnt/usb` everything that you write under `/mnt/usb` with be written directly to the usb drive and should never touch the sdcard. You will need to mount the usb each time it is inserted or you reboot the device unless you configure it to automatically mount upon detection/boot. You will also want to ensure that you use the command: `umount /mnt/usb` before removing the drive, so it has a chance to sync any unwritten data to the drive.